# Chrome extension : Get discord webhooks content when it is posted in a channel

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, discord

I made a little chrome extension which take webhook contents as parameters.

Here's the content_script.js of my extension :

```js
f = function(){
 var test = $( "div.embedDescription-1Cuq9a:last" ).text();
 var cs_rep_1 = test.split('1 : "');
 var cs_rep_1 = cs_rep_1[1].split('"');
 var cs_rep_1 = cs_rep_1[0];
 var cs_rep_2 = test.split('2 : "');
 var cs_rep_2 = cs_rep_2[1].split('"');
 var cs_rep_2 = cs_rep_2[0];
 var cs_rep_3 = test.split('3 : "');
 var cs_rep_3 = cs_rep_3[1].split('"');
 var cs_rep_3 = cs_rep_3[0];
 var totalElements = '&cs_rep_1='+cs_rep_1+'&cs_rep_2='+cs_rep_2+'&cs_rep_3='+cs_rep_3;
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage({total_elements: totalElements});
 
}
document.body.addEventListener('dblclick',f);
```

As you can see it is triggered only if I double click in the tab where the webhook is posted.
I'd like to trigger it when a new webhook is posted, that's to say when a new div with this the class embedDescription-1Cuq9a is created in the tab.
Any ideas on how to do this ?

Comment: That's a job for MutationObserver.

Comment: Thanks you it was exactly what i was looking for !